# Symfony 2 & Remember me function

Tags: symfony, cookies, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle, remember-me

Having a strange problem that others don't seem to have.
I can't get the "remember me" function working on my Symfony 2.1 app.

I've tried local and deployed on a server, I've tried with and without the FOS User Bundle and I just can't seem to get it working.

It's a basic setup from composer and nothing is missing, the security is working fine and I can login, logout, create new users, etc, etc.

It's creating the session cookie fine (checked that) but I think there is meant to be a second cookie that it's not creating?

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login_firewall:
            pattern:      ^/login$
            anonymous:    ~
        main:
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
                path:     /
                domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: We had a similar issue when using an event listener to redirect users depending on roles after login.  If you are using a similar listener you will not be able to use the remember me functionality as the listener returns a redirect before the remember me cookie is created.  see http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/ for a different method of redirecting if you are doing so.

Comment: Thanks Luke, but it was a simple remember_me: true on the form login. Even if I have to force TRUE that will do me fine for this app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the settings from here:

```
security:
    # ...

    form_login:
        # ...
        remember_me: true
    remember_me:
        # ...
        always_remember_me: true
```

Comment: I don't want to show the remember_me button what can I do?

Comment: `always_remember_me` does exactly that.